# Is there an real advantage on using the correct HTTP methods?

Tags: http, post, get

Most people use **GET** and **POST** for all of their requisitions, are there any major problems that should be considered a real reason to respect the [correct semanthics](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1)?

What are the disadvantages on the lack of using "HEAD","PUT","DELETE","TRACE",etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of every HTTP verb is known by clients (like browsers) and intermediate equipments as well. They treat requests accordingly (in terms of logging, caching, replaying, etc...)

Some examples:

- A `GET`/`HEAD` request is considered "safe" and can be replayed a number of times without breaking anything. On the other hand, a `POST` request is not considered "safe" because it implies a remote state modification. That's why when you navigate by posting a form, and you click the "back" button of your browser, your browser asks if you want to `POST` the form again
- A `GET` request should be used to retrieve a remote resource. That's why the resource can be cached in intermediate HTTP-aware equipments in order to reduce the number of requests on the backend systems. The response of a `GET` request is considered cacheable (it's implemented in [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), web servers, HTTP proxies, etc...).
- If you use a `GET` request in place of a `POST`, that means you're sending the payload in the URL and that means potential sensitive data logged by the backend, and all of the intermediate equipments (an URL is considered as a loggable non sensitive information)
- About `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, there is no major concern about using a `POST` instead of one of these, they're here to help you build self-documented RESTful APIs, define fine-grained authorizations on the endpoints and are pretty similar to `POST` when we forget the semantics (non cacheable, non replayable, hold the data in the body, if concerned)

Answer (score 0):

GET requests are generally for requesting data and POST is for sending data. The biggest difference is that GET parameters are visible in the URL after a "?" while POST is sent in the header of the request. POST requests are more secure in this way and should be used to send sensitive data such as passwords. GET requests can be used to send parameters through just the URL. For example if your website dynamically loads pages based on parameters, it is useful to use get. Youtube uses get to pass the video id.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ